# Mark detected email address in text view like in iPhone mail app

Tags: ios, nsattributedstring

I am using `NSDataDetector` to detect email addresses in user text in a text view, Then I am setting the attributed text of the text view to change the colour of the detected text.

Wel it works great, but now I am trying to figure out how to set the detected text the same style as in the mail app :

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Well you can set the text view to recognize the addresses in IB.  Images aren't showing up for me so I'm not totally sure what you want.  What do you mean by how they appear in the mail app.

Comment: Your question is a little confusing - you used the ios tag and mentioned the iPhone mail app, but your screenshot is from the desktop mail app - please clarify.